# Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method (Should not happen)

Tags: java, events, mouse

I have a program to create a JFrame and it should print out the coordinates of a mouse hovering over the JFrame window whenever it is moved. I keep getting this error "Helper is not abstract and does not override abstract method" and it doesn't make any sense to me. My function Helper shouldn't need to be abstract and it already overrides the new implementation from the initial class.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class Event extends JFrame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  JFrame a = new JFrame();

  a.setVisible(true);

  a.setSize(300, 300);

  a.addMouseMotionListener(new Helper());

  }

}


class Helper implements MouseMotionListener {

  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

  int x = e.getX(), y = e.getY();

  System.out.println("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");

  }

  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

  System.out.println("");}

}
```

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me.

Comment: Does this error persist after recompile?

Comment: I had this code in a folder with a previously defined .class file with the name Helper. The error is what really threw me off but I figured it out by deleting that old .class file and recompiling.